# What does (?i) mean in a Python/pexpect regex?

Tags: python, regex, pexpect, pxssh

I'm trying to understand what the repeated `(?i)` syntax means in the following code:

```
i = self.expect([
  "(?i)are you sure you want to continue connecting",
  original_prompt,
  "(?i)(?:password)|(?:passphrase for key)",
  "(?i)permission denied",
  "(?i)terminal type",
  TIMEOUT,
  "(?i)connection closed by remote host"
], timeout=login_timeout)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is documented under the heading for `(?aiLmsux-imsx:...)` in https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html, as follows:

> `(?aiLmsux-imsx:...)`
>
> (Zero or more letters from the set `a`, `i`, `L`, `m`, `s`, `u`, `x`, optionally followed by `-` followed by one or more letters from the `i`, `m`, `s`, `x`.) The letters set or remove the corresponding flags: `re.A` (ASCII-only matching), **`re.I` (ignore case)**, `re.L` (locale dependent), `re.M` (multi-line), `re.S` (dot matches all), `re.U` (Unicode matching), and `re.X` (verbose), for the part of the expression. (The flags are described in Module Contents.)

Thus, `(?i)` is an inline version of the flag that is otherwise set as `re.I`, or `re.IGNORECASE`; it makes the match case-insensitive, such that `permission denied` could also be written `Permission Denied` or `PERMISSION DENIED` but would still be matched.